# Is it possible to mark or segregate bad blocks on HDD?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning, storage, bad-blocks

Hello I want to know if is it possible to mark bad blocks on HDD for OS to not use them. I don't want to save data written on this blocks, just want to get rid of them.

I found some article where author describe how to partition disk to avoid using bad blocks of HDD. [Here is screen of surface scan of my HDD.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uoxhg.png) I count how many MB from the start are OK. And also how many MB from end are OK. It looks like I will lost about 50GB of storage space but it is quite fine for me when the disk will run one year more.

First I split disk to 2 partitions:

1. From beginning to around 190 GB
2. From 190GB to the end

Then I made surface scan of 2nd partition and everything was OK. I was really happy cause i though that finally I will succeed.

Than I wanted to copy all data from 1st partition to 2nd BUT in some data a problem occurs. I/O error. I'd say it is Read problem but when I open file on which copying failed it runs OK, for example some pdf files didn't copied but I opened them.

What can be problem can it be a Write problem? But why there is a problem when surface scan on whole 2nd partition was fine?

What can I do(except buying new HDD)? Can I somehow do this partitioning and use just partition with good sectors? Will it work? How are data stored on the disk? Can I determine where the data will be written?

Answer (score 1):

Modern hard disks support Self-Monitoring, Analysis, and Reporting Technology (SMART), which automatically maps out bad blocks, replacing them from a pool of blocks that are OK. If you're seeing bad blocks at the OS level, that means that your disk has run out of its "emergency supply" of backup blocks. Normally this is a sign that the disk is on its last legs. Although it *could* last for months with just that one bad block, it's more likely to begin developing more bad blocks in the near future. In fact, it may do so catastrophically, with the number of bad blocks spreading to consume vast quantities of your data in a matter of minutes.

Thus, I do not recommend using a software solution to map out your one bad block; instead, replace the whole disk. Although tools to map out individual bad blocks do exist, they were written for pre-SMART hard disks, when a handful of bad blocks were common on brand-new disks. Today, the only safe course of action really is to replace the disk.

Comment: Yes my drive run out of spare blocks in pool. Now I have around 70 bad blocks. It is really lot, but, what it is if no more block will damage soon? As I said now it's not so critical to loose for example 50GB of storage space. I don't need it, now. I have enough free space beside of loosing this 50GB. I asked, If I make partition in which the surface scan will be OK an I will use this partition for storing data, will it be OK? Will data be written just there or will they be written on bad blocks? Will damage of HDD spread in future days rapidly? How it will happen? What causes damage to HDD?

Comment: @Gondil damage to the hard drive is part of the aging process.  Although dropping it, stepping on it, or other physical actions can damage them this type of damage is uncommon.  Laptop hard drives suffer from drops more because they are portable and easily dropped.

Comment: @cybernard I understand that every thing has its life. But, I had a previous disk 3 years and had also OS on it. That laptop used my sister for a year too so it lived really long :P And after this I sold it with no issues on it. I bought SSD for OS+soft and 2nd HDD just for data. HDD was "used", BUT seller told me he just replacet this HDD with SSD in new laptop so it wasn't used at all. I have it for 3-4 months and it is seriously damaged. For this it make me angry and I'm trying to for it to live for some time longer.

Comment: Gondil, your scenario includes one critical word: *if*. *If* your disk degrades no further, you can do as you suggest and get away with it. That's like leaving your laundry drying outside on a day when the forecast is for rain, though. I cannot in good conscience recommend that you do it -- the odds of more bad blocks appearing, much like the odds of rain, are far too high.

Answer (score 0):

Although I would go with replacing the hard drive as Rod Smith suggested here is how it is done.

If you have windows with NTFS or FAT file system you go to an administrative command prompt and type:

chkdsk /r c:

(You may substitute any drive letter you want for the c:)

It will ask you if you want to schedule this for next reboot.  Say YES.
Reboot and let it scan.

Now if you drive gets new bad sectors you will have to scan all over again.

Comment: I also made chkdsk D: /r but in fact that drive is seriously damaged and have no more spare sectors chkdsk stucked.

Comment: @Gondil  chkdsk does not use spare sectors.  It simply hides bad sectors and there is no upper limit that I am aware of.  If it appears to be stuck it just means you have a bunch in a row.  Please run it over night so it has at least 8 uninterrupt hours of scan time.

Comment: @Gondil otherwise you will have to use mhdd or buy spinrite.

Comment: hmm this sounds new for me.. Truly, chkdsk shows me message that there "is not enough space" or something like that. For this it stucked. What else can it be when not spare sectors which are certainly out. Disk is 500GB and has around 360GB free space. There are many users here who told me that its not about physical free space but about spare sectors

Comment: Maybe I will try mhdd. But I'm really tired of it yet. I wan to save data, save disk for a while maybe(save money),... Finally I will probably sell it for 10€ and will be happy that I get something for that piece of crap..

Comment: @Gondil Hard drives have hidden spare sectors usually 60-200.  The SMART system can and will use those up.  However, chkdsk can not interact with those spare sectors.  chkdsk may cause the hdd SMART to re-allocate a sector but it can not do it itself.  Given your previous message I suggest mhdd. http://hddguru.com  and download the ISO version and burn to CD.

Comment: I only want to ask, mhdd will format my disk or data will remain if there are not damaged?

Comment: your data will be unharmed.

Comment: It showed message that my disk is not ready, that it do not support LBA mode. I made scan with partitioning tool by Dmitri Primochenko. It scanned my disk for bad blocks and when the soft found good block larger than some value you choose, it made a partition on disk which is not in the bad blocks. And that was my question is it ok to use disk like this partitioned for some unimportant data? And what do you think why the mhdd does not work correctly, I don't know how to run it well. I ran it from MS-DOS USB with mhdd on it. It started but it shows that my disk is not ready. what should I do?

Comment: Go into your bios and switch the controller from ahci to ide,standard, or similiar mode.

Comment: Thanks now it runs.. but it is really slow. It runs for 2 days and one night and it is just in a third. Remapping is really slow :/

Comment: Yes, it is slow, but effective.  I have a spare computer I put in a dark corner for this, I have had hard drives with tons of bad sectors run for 3+ weeks.