# With raw disk, before Partition, before filesystem, how to map bad blocks?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, filesystems

using:
`neofetch --stdout |grep 'OS:'`
OS: Kubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64

After zeroing disk with:

```
time sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sd_ bs=1M status=progress               #Zero_disk_delete_wipe
```

We have a raw disk = All zeros = `unrecognized` is term stated by `fdisk -l`

edit
`fdisk -l`  is incorrect
`sudo parted -l` is correct

thus
`sudo parted -l |grep -i 'Error'`
`Error: /dev/sda: unrecognised disk label`

With a raw disk, before doing `ext4` filesystem, how to map bad blocks?
What program?
What command?
Is it possible to map bad blocks on a raw disk, before filesystem and before Partition?

.
.

Guess is -- we must have a filesystem before mapping bad blocks.
Please confirm above Guess.

.
.

With raw disk, `ext4` filesystem was done, 6 steps:

```
sudo parted --align opt /dev/sd_ mktable gpt                              #Make_Partition_Table GPT 
sudo parted --align opt /dev/sd_ mkpart PART_1  0% 100%                   #ext4 Partition disk / Label 
sync; sudo partprobe ; sudo parted /dev/sda align-check optimal 1 ; sync  #Okresult = 1 aligned 
time sudo mkfs.ext4 -L _xxxxG_GEX4 /dev/sd_1                              #ext4_wait_17_seconds G=GPT EX4=ext4 filesystem
sync; sudo chgrp adm /media/u3/_xxxxG_GEX4 ;sync                          #disk permissions for ext4 not NTFS 
sync; sudo chmod g+w /media/u3/_xxxxG_GEX4 ;sync                          #disk permissions for ext4 not NTFS
```

After filesystem then map bad blocks:

```
time sudo e2fsck    -fccky      /dev/sd_1                              #6hours/1000GBor1TB sd_1 has filesystem ext4
```

```
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
Checking for bad blocks (non-destructive read-write test)
Testing with random pattern: done                                                 
_xxxxG_GEX4: Updating bad block inode.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
_xxxxG_GEX4: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
_xxxxG_GEX4: 11/61054976 files (0.0% non-contiguous), 4114691/244190208 blocks
real    340m11.067s = 20411.067 seconds ~ 6hours 
user    0m0.292s
sys     0m1.126s

HDD
sudo blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sd_ 
1000204886016 bytes / 20411.067 seconds = 49,003,067 ~ 49MB/s
```

refer:
"Modern hard disks support
Self-Monitoring, Analysis, and Reporting Technology (SMART),
which automatically maps out bad blocks,
replacing them from a pool of blocks that are OK.
If you're seeing bad blocks at the OS level,
that means that your disk has run out of its "emergency supply" of backup blocks.
Normally this is a sign that the disk is on its last legs.
Although it could last for months with just that one bad block,
it's more likely to begin developing more bad blocks in the near future.
In fact, it may do so catastrophically,
with the number of bad blocks spreading to consume vast quantities of your
data in a matter of minutes."
[Is it possible to mark or segregate bad blocks on HDD?](https://superuser.com/questions/772019/is-it-possible-to-mark-or-segregate-bad-blocks-on-hdd)

.
.

Question:
Is it possible to map bad blocks on a raw disk, before filesystem?

Said differently,
Before Partition is done and
Before choosing `NTFS` filesystem or
Before choosing `ext4` filesystem
Is it possible to map bad blocks on a raw disk, before above 2 filesystems?

--

Answer (score 4):

Linux has the **badblocks** command reference here:

https://linux.die.net/man/8/badblocks

Also see here

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/badblocks-command-in-linux-with-examples/

```
badblocks -o out.txt -s /dev/sdb
```

-sn is a non-destructive write test

-sw is a destructive write test

Comment: At https://linux.die.net/man/8/badblocks  
Important note: 
If the output of badblocks is going to be fed to the 
e2fsck or 
mke2fs programs, it is important that the 
block size is properly specified, 
since the block numbers which are generated are very dependent on the 
block size in use by the filesystem. 
For this reason, it is strongly recommended that users 
not run badblocks directly, 
but rather use the -c option of the 
e2fsck and 
mke2fs programs.

command issued was: 
```time sudo e2fsck    -fccky      /dev/sd_1```

Comment: The command ```badblocks -o out.txt -s /dev/sd_1``` is understood 
to be based on a Partitioned disk and a filesystem (Formatted Partition).  
Formatted Partition with ```ext4```.  
With ```ext4``` filesystem the following command took over 8 hours / 1000GB. 
```time sudo badblocks -o out.txt -sn -b 4096 -c 4096 /dev/sd_1``` 
out.txt was Zero bytes.  sd_1 = sda1 or sdb1 or etc...

But, the Question is:

Comment: But, the Question is:  

Is it possible to map bad blocks on a raw disk, before filesystem?  
How to map bad blocks on a raw disk? 
A raw disk = All zeros on disk.  (No Partition, No filesystem) 
A raw disk also = ```unrecognized``` is term stated by ```fdisk -l``` .

Comment: you use badblocks with /dev/sda or sdb , the partition number is optional.  I removed the number from my answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: @joseph22 Nowadays you don't feed the output of badblocks to `e2fsck` or `mke2fs` nor ask these tools to use `badblocks` internally. This was a way for ext to avoid bad sectors, it made sense before SMART. With SMART the disk itself remaps bad sectors so the filesystem (or `badblocks`) will see good spare sectors, except when a sector cannot be remapped yet or after the spare pool runs out. Writing to a pending (bad) sector should force-remap it, unless the pool has run out. If `badblocks` sees bad blocks in a write test, the disk is "on its last legs". You should first check SMART.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski  I have run across many cases where SMART does not remap bad sectors when it should even when it said it had spare sectors.  The OP seem like they might be trying to partition around the bad sectors.

Comment: @cybernard Did you attempt to *explicitly* write to bad sectors each time? It's normal for a bad sector that potentially holds important data to remain as-is in hope some read attempt in the future will succeed; this is what I meant by "cannot be remapped yet". Attempting to write (in fact overwrite) indicates we've given up on the old data; then the sector gets remapped. But if a disk *really* does not remap when it can and shall then it's even less trustworthy. Your answer is good and I have already voted up. I was addressing the OP's comment where they mentioned `e2fsck` and `mke2fs`.

Comment: cybernard typed: "The OP seem like they might be trying to 
partition around the bad sectors."  No.  As far as i understand the dd command;  
the entire disk was filled with zeros with 
```time sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sd_ bs=1M status=progress #Zero_disk_delete_wipe``` 
No extra effort was taken to "partition around the bad sectors." 
and Question was correctd see ```sudo parted -l``` 
thus ```sudo parted -l |grep -i 'Error'``` shows ```Error: /dev/sda: unrecognised disk label``` 
pointing out ```unrecognised disk``` means a raw disk = No Partition, No filesystem.

Comment: Question was: with raw disk = all Zeros = No Data, No Partition, 
No filesystem, how to map bad blocks?  
from above comments i understand there is 
no program that i can easily run that maps bad blocks with a raw disk.  
Because disk was zeroed again, made raw again, with :

Comment: Because disk was zeroed again, made raw again, with : 
```time sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sd_ bs=1M status=progress #Zero_disk_delete_wipe``` 
and ```sudo smartctl -i /dev/sda``` output was 
```smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-6.2.0-36-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org
Read NVMe Identify Controller failed: scsi error unsupported scsi opcode``` 
which i understand to mean a failed command, meaning 
smartctl 7.2 is not for a raw disk but 
smartctl 7.2 works on a disk with ```ext4``` filesystem.

Comment: @joseph22 `badblocks` does give you a map, i.e. a file containing positions of bad blocks. If you mean "map out" like in the citation: "automatically maps out bad blocks, replacing them from a pool of blocks that are OK", then zeroing with `dd` should have forced this, *if possible* (i.e. if the pool is not depleted).

Comment: Kamil Maciorowski typed: 
If you mean "map out" like in the citation: 
"automatically maps out bad blocks, 
replacing them from a pool of blocks that are OK", 
then zeroing with dd should have forced this, 
if possible (i.e. if the pool is not depleted).  
On a ```raw``` disk = all zeros, how can dd map out bad blocks?  ...

Comment: On a ```raw``` disk = all zeros, how can dd map out bad blocks? 
Meaning, say the disk pool is not depleted and command is:  
```time sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sd_ bs=1M status=progress #Zero_disk_delete_wipe``` 
the words ```map``` and ```pool``` and ```bad blocks``` not found in 2 references. 
```man dd>dd.txt``` and 
```https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix)#Recovery-oriented_variants_of_dd``` 
With raw disk, what is the dd command to map bad blocks? 
With raw disk, how to measure pool of reserved OK blocks before dd and after dd mapping?

Comment: @joseph22  dd by itself doesn't map out the bad block.  When dd writes to a block it causes the drives built in SMART to review the sector and decide whether it wrote to the disk reliably.  If the SMART decides the sectors is bad it does the actually remapping.  SMART is part of the drives firmware.  **smartctl -a /dev/sda** will let you review the SMART data.  However, you may have to download and install separately.  If the sector isn't read/written to SMART does NOT check the sector.

Comment: Testing sata m.2 Memory 1000GB = 1TB, looks similar to: 
https://www.newegg.ca/western-digital-blue-1tb/p/N82E16820250092

testing was done with:  usb Enclosure = NexStar SX, USB 3.2 Gen2x1 Type C M.2 NVMe/SATA RGB Enclosure
https://www.vantecusa.com/products_detail.php?p_id=287 __ continue >

Comment: Changing hardware connection for above sata m.2 Memory 1000GB = 1TB, 
might help output more information with commands like: 
```smartctl -a /dev/sda``` 
__Change from above usb enclosure 
to sata m.2 adapter that looks similar to: 
https://www.amazon.ca/ELUTENG-22-Pin-Converter-Adapter-Desktop/dp/B07VX615T9?th=1 __